# Is there a way to set UIBackgroundModes in iOS on the iPhone programmatically?

Tags: iphone, ios, dynamic, background, location

I would like to be able to set the UIBackgroundModes setting for updating my location dynamically (with a UISwitch setting) from my gui.  I can handle the UISwitch stuff just fine, but, I would like to be able to get the user to be able to "turn on" location updating even when the app is in the background.  I imagine, that if I AM able to do this, then, I would need to update some data structure in memory, as well as update my Info.plist file...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can only set this in Info.plist, which cannot be modified after the app is built.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use code to change it. You can only change it **before** you compile by edit your `xx-info.plist` file. `UIBackgroundModes` is one of the iOS keys you can use in `info.plist` file. See what Apple says about the `info.plist` file

Here is [info.plist's description](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Introduction/Introduction.html).

> About Info.plist Keys
>
> To provide a better experience for users, iOS and OS X rely on the
>   presence of special meta information in each app or bundle. This meta
>   information is used in many different ways. Some of it is displayed to
>   the user, some of it is used internally by the system to identify your
>   app and the document types it supports, and some of it is used by the
>   system frameworks to facilitate the launch of apps. **The way an app
>   provides its meta information to the system is through the use of a
>   special file called an information property list file**.

Here is [iOS keys' description](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW1).

> iOS Keys
>
> The iOS frameworks provide the infrastructure you need for creating
>   iOS apps. You use the keys associated with this framework to configure
>   the appearance of your app at launch time and the behavior of your app
>   once it is running.